# Why ng-click not working in a dynamic html content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

I have a web application working with angular js and it has selection to select some master data. It is working perfectly fine. My only problem is I create a dynamic button inside a table and I have attached ng-click method to that button, however, it is not working and it does not give any kind of a respone either.

ng-click='ssa' is the call and $scopr.ssa = function(){} has alert method to get a the method is called or not

```
myApp.controller('oppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.MasterSelection = [{ id: 1, name: 'Contact' }, { id: 2, name: 'Property Category' }, { id: 3, name: 'Property Features' }, { id: 4, name: 'Sale or Rent' }];

        $scope.MasterChange = function () {

            var Type = $scope.master.name;
            var Value = $scope.newtype;

            var Master = new DataAdd(Type, Value);

            $.ajax({
                url: "../api/operations/mastertables",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Master: Master
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    SetDP(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    alert(exception);

                }
            });
            $scope.experror = "SDsd";
        }

          $scope.ssa = function () { alert('qw');}

    function SetDP(data) {
        var tables = '<table width="60%"><col width="15%"/><col width="20%"/><col width="65%"/><tbody>';

        if (data != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                tables += '<tr>';
                tables += '<td> <img style="width:40px; height:40px;" src=@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/btndelete.png") /> </td>';
                tables += '<td> <label style="font-size:x-small; color:white;">' + (i + 1) + '</label> </td>';
                tables += '<td> <label style="font-size:x-small; color:white;">' + data[i][1] + '</label> </td>';
                tables += '</tr>';
            }
        }

        tables += '<tr><td> <button style="width:80px; height:30px; font-size:15px;" ng-click="ssa();"> Add </button> </td><td></td>';
        tables += '<td> <input style="font-size:20px; width:100%;"  type="text" ng-model="newtype" /></td></tr>';
        tables += '</tbody></table>';

        $("#dvtable").html(tables);

    }

        function DataAdd(Type, Value) {
            this.Type = Type;
            this.Value = Value;
        }
    }]);
```

Following would be my html code

```
<select ng-model="master" ng-options="master.name for master in MasterSelection" ng-change="MasterChange()">
      <option value="">None</option>
    </select>
      <div ng-bind-html="dvtable">

      </div>
```

How should I make my button clickable in angular js application? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use a directive to pass a templateUrl

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: this is really a wrong approach, and not "the angular way".  You should never be modifying the DOM directly in this way using angular; instead, make a template, assign your "dynamic" values to an array, and use `ng-repeat` to write the template for each value.  Mixing JQuery and angular is almost never necessary.

Comment: As I say EVERY day on one question or another about angular, you should always be coding against your data, never coding against the DOM.

Comment: @Claies Do you have any example?

Comment: I was going to attempt to try to rewrite this as a more angular function using `$http` instead of `$.ajax` and using `ng-repeat` rather than using `$("#dvtable").html(tables);` but I find myself having trouble understanding what this does.  Every time you *change* the dropdown, it does a **Post** to the server, with some value that it gets from some field you haven't shown, and then displays some data of an unknown format.  can you post your expected and actual results, so that it's more obvious what you are really trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="master" ng-options="master.name for master in MasterSelection" ng-change="MasterChange()">
      <option value="">None</option>
</select>

<my-table>

</my-table>
```

//js

```
(function(){

myApp.directive('myTable', function(){

 return {
  restrict : 'E',
  templateUrl : 'my-table.template.html',
  link : function(scope){
    scope.ssa = function(){
      alert("HELLO");
    }
  }

  };

});


})();
```

//my-table.template.html

```
<div> <button class="btn btn-default ng-click="ssa()"> Click </button> </div>
```